# Garbled image after login

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, login-screen

The login wallpaper (in LightDM) is gone, and after I input the password the screen goes all garbled and it stays there for five minutes or so, after that it logs in fine.

This used to be a minor annoyance because I usually leave my PC on, but since now I turn it off on a daily basis it's quite boring to stay there and stare at the broken screen.

The garbled screen seems to be somehow related to which applications were open at the moment of the previous shutdown. For instance, in the attached screenshots it shows icons of Nautilus and Firefox, and both were open. Sometimes it just shows a checkerboard pattern of green and black boxes all of the same dimension.

HARDWARE:
Graphics card is an NVidia GTX660 with driver version 331.38. Please don't suggest to use the Nouveau opensource driver because I need the proprietary driver (I play on that machine).
Processor is an AMD Phenom X4. Although I doubt that would depend on the processor.

SOFTWARE:
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS AMD64, kernel 3.13.0-38-generic

How can I get rid of the garbled screen AND get the login screen wallpaper back?

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the issue. I restored the wallpaper using Ubuntu Tweak. That magically fixed the garbled screen login.